# Changing the architecture to AFNetworking in iOS

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am new to iOS development.

I have an application which uses `NSURLConnection` methods for http transfers across the network. The application is using JSON classes `SBJsonparser` and `SBJsonWriter` classes for parsing the Json and Serialization protocols for coverting the objects to json and deserializing the specified dictionary into instace of objects and using Serialization properties. I have separate classes for each request to API which conforms to serializable protocol.

One of sample classes is as follows

```
+ (id) deserializeFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary  {
          Class *obj = [super deserializeFromDictionary:dictionary];
         return obj;
    }



+ (NSArray *) serializableProperties  {

           static NSArray *properties = nil;

           if (properties == nil)  {
               properties = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                      [SerializableProperty propertyWithExternalName:@"username" 
                      internalName:@"username" internalClass:[NSString class]],
                      [SerializableProperty propertyWithExternalName:@"pwd" 
                      internalName:@"pwd" internalClass:[NSDate class]],
                      nil];
           }

           return properties;
     }

      - (NSDictionary *) serializeToDictionary {
            NSMutableDictionary *userDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary 
            dictionaryWithDictionary:[super serializeToDictionary]];
            return userDictionary;
       }
```

Now I have to replace the whole architecture with `AFNetworking`

I have replaced the

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

with the following AFNetworking.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]  
                                     initWithRequest:request];
/// validates and decodes JSON responses.
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

      // succes code

 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

       // failure code

 }];

 // 5
 [operation start];
```

My Question is, is this ok or do I need to change the serialization of objects also? Is it possible to replace the serialization protocol with any of the `AFNetworking` Classes?. If YES, please let me know how to change this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does the parameters mean for Post method. Is these are parameters to included in query string? How to attach the JSON as body to the request in POST and PUT methods using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager?

Answer (score 0):

Your can use the following code.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager POST:urlparameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // Success Code
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
       // Failure Code
 }];
```

You can use GET/POST depending on your requirements. Using AFNetworking you don't need to handle JSON parsing manually.